# Automatically respond to Matlab uigetfile

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to script a response to Matlab's `uigetfile`?

For example, I have a script saved as p code (uneditable) that contains calls to `uigetfile`. Normally, a user would run the script and manually select a file using the file browser created by `uigetfile`. If a user wanted to run the script on a thousand input files, the user would have to manually select every file using the file browser.

So, is there a way to run the pcode from another script and automatically respond to `uigetfile`'s file browser. I realize that the best solution would be to do away with `uigetfile`, but that is not feasible in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `uigetfile` in a p-file, unfortunately there is nothing you can do with Matlab.

You can have a look at [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), though. It is a graphical automating software, which can handle the `uigetfile` popups for you.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thank you for the Sikuli reference.